# Docker namespaces preventing sqlite3 database access

Tags: sqlite, docker, namespaces

I have [mouthful](https://github.com/vkuznecovas/mouthful) comments running inside a Docker container with namespaces enabled.
Mouthful loads on my web page, but I cannot post comments. In the Docker log I get the following error message as well as a `500` error in the dev tools console.

```
attempt to write a readonly database
[GIN] 2018/12/16 - 11:57:23 | 500 |    1.956915ms |        10.0.0.0 | POST     /v1/comments
```

Inside the mouthful container with namespaces **enabled**, I notice the config.json and database file are set as nobody user.

```
/app # ls -la /app/data
total 40
drwxr-xr-x    2 nobody   nobody        4096 Dec 15 21:48 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Aug 27 16:25 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 nobody   nobody        1460 Dec 16 11:55 config.json
-rw-r--r--    1 nobody   nobody       24576 Dec 15 21:48 mouthful.db
```

If I run mouthful with namespaces **disabled** (using --userns=host) mouthful runs OK and I am able to post comments.
Inside the container with namespaces disabled the files permissions are set as root.

```
/app # ls -la /app/data
total 40
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Dec 16 12:20 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 123000   123000        4096 Aug 27 16:25 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          1460 Dec 16 12:18 config.json
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root         24576 Dec 16 12:20 mouthful.db
```

The problem with this is the process on the host is also set as root.

```
ps au | grep [b]in/sh
root      8420  0.5  0.0   1560   516 pts/0    Ss+  12:24   0:00 /bin/sh
```

I believe this to be a security risk because it makes it easier for someone to gain root access to the host.

So, how can I get sqlite3 to work with Mouthful comments with Docker namespaces enabled?

Comment: Have you considered giving the user the `mouthful` container runs as write permissions to the SQLite3 file in the machine? If you start your Docker container as `root` consider looking into the `--user` option which allows you to run your Docker container under another user ID.

Comment: I tried changing the user when I `docker run` the container like `--user=nobody:nobody`,  but I get a message in the `dockers logs` file `panic: Couldn't override the static admin script path. Please check if the script file(./static/bundle.baa67.js) is available and the mouthful user has the permissions to access it`.